# Open flash chart : How to display projected data

Tags: charts, open-flash-chart

I am using open flash chart to display a chart in my page. I am using the below code to display the line chart data to my page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
swfobject.embedSWF("open-flash-chart.swf", "my_chart", "530", "250","9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",
{"data-file":"data.json"}
);
</script>
```

and my json file is as follows

```
{

  "y_legend":{
        "text": "Price US$",
         "style": "{color: #53B9AA;font-size:20; }"
            },

  "elements":[
   {
   "type": "line",
   "colour": "#53B9AA",
    "bg_colour": "#E58A25",
    "background-color":"#53B9AA",
    "inner_background": "#E58A25",
    "text": "Price History",
    "font-size": 19,
    "width": 1,
    "dot-style": {
    "type":"solid-dot", "colour":"#F57F22", "dot-size": 3,
         "tip":"Average price: #val#<br>#x_label#" },
         "on-show": {"type": "shrink-in", "cascade":1, "delay":0.7},
          "values" : [
                 5,7,10,12,13,{"value":11,"colour":"#53B9AA","tip":"Average price :  #val#<br>#x_label#"},
  10,9,8,7,6]
}
],

  "x_axis":{
  "colour": "#7CC8B5",
  "text": "Price US$",
  "labels": {
  "rotate": "vertical",
  "labels":["Jan-09","Feb-09","Mar-09",
  "Apr-09","May-09","Jun-09",
  "Jul-09","Aug-09","Sep-09",
  "Oct-09","Nov-09","Dec-09",
  "Jan-10","Feb-10","Mar-10"]
  }
 },

 "y_axis":{
 "stroke": 4,
  "tick-length": 10,
  "colour": "#7CC8B5",
  "grid-colour": "#ADB5C7",
   "grid-visible": true,
   "offset": false,
    "min": 5,
     "max": 20,
     "visible": true,
     "steps": 5
   }
}
```

The chart is rendering in my browser pretty well. Now I want to add some more data to chart. Basically my chart is displaying the average sales for past few months. I want to show the projected/forecasted/future data also.I can pass that data to the jSON file. I want the future data to be in a different color in the chart. And I want to display the legends too in the top of the chart to indicate which one is current data and which one is future data.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use different lines for the current and projected data.

You can add multiple lines to a single chart, but this might not suit your purposes, since (currently at least), line charts need to have data for the whole x-axis range, and any null values are interpolated.

One option is to use the patched version from [this site](http://ofc2dz.com/OFC2/downloads/ofc2Downloads.html), set [null-gap:true](http://ofc2dz.com/OFC2/examples/MiscellaneousPatches.html) and use null data values to pad the line positions.

The option is to use the normal version of the flash object and use scatter charts as in this example:  http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/scatter-mixed.php